# how to make query in specific table in default.relam that contains many tables in android

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm a beginner in realm in android and I want to make table name detection in my query.

this is my code

> `realm.where(TafseerQuraanModel.class).findAll();`

Comment: What? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: how to make query in specific table in this db

Comment: What column do you want to query?

Comment: please understand me. Quraan.realm has 4 tables. I want to make query in one of them to get data from it.
do you understand me? @nbokmans

Comment: Do you mean you want to dynamically open a realm query on one of the tables? Like you want to substitute `TafseerQuraanModel.class` for another one of those tables? You could use reflection to get the class type: `try { Class clazzType = Class.forName("nl.nbokmans.model.TafseerQuraanModel"); RealmList<TafseerQuraanModel> = realm.where(clazzType).findAll(); } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> realm.where(TafseerQuraanModel.class)
> ```

This line already returns a `Query` that is being executed for table `TafseerQuaanModel`.

So things like this work:

```
realm.where(TafseerQuraanModel.class)
        .equalTo("name", "blah")
     .findAllSorted("name", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

For more information on queries, [***read the official documentation***](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries).